# Limit of a sequence that looks like $e$

Tags: real-analysis

How does one go about calculating the limit of the sequence
$$a_n = \left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n^2} \right)^n.$$ I understand the cases of 
$
b_n = \left(\alpha + \dfrac{\beta}{n}\right)^n,
$
in terms of $e$, but I am missing the "trick" with regards to $a_n$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572209/test-f-n-1-frac1n2n-for-convergence-and-give-its-limit-if-it-exists https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562459/prove-that-1-n-2-n-to-1/1562478#1562478 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736525/computing-lim-limits-n-to-infty11-n2n/736882#736882  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736525/computing-lim-limits-n-to-infty11-n2n https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736525/computing-lim-limits-n-to-infty11-n2n/736539#736539 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562459/prove-that-1-n-2-n-to-1/1562473#1562473

Comment: Is the search function that hard to use ? And of course everybody is jumping to answer it, come on...

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n^{2}}\rightarrow e$, then $n^{2}\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\rightarrow\log e=1$. Now
\begin{align*}
n\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot n^{2}\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\rightarrow 0\cdot 1=0,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}\rightarrow e^{0}=1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$1\le\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n^2} \right)^n=\left[\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n^2} \right)^{n^2}\right]^\frac1n\le e^\frac1n$$

thus for squeeze theorem

$$\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n^2} \right)^n\to 1$$

Comment: Gimusi. Very nice, you do not forget to bound below:)))

Answer (score 2):

As long as you know the binomial theorem, you don't need to know anything about $e$:

$$\begin{align}
1\le\left(1+{1\over n^2}\right)^n
&=1+{n\over n^2}+{{n\choose2}\over n^4}+\cdots+{{n\choose n}\over n^{2n}}\\
&\le1+{1\over n}+{n^2\over n^4}+\cdots+{n^n\over n^{2n}}\\
&\le1+{1\over n}+{1\over n^2}+\cdots+{1\over n^n}+\cdots\\
&={1\over1-{1\over n}}\to1
\end{align}$$

Comment: In the last equality wouldn't it be as follow? $$={{1-\left(\frac1n\right)^{n+1}}\over1-{1\over n}}\to1$$

Comment: @gimusi, the line above the last line extended the finite sum to the infinite geometric series.

Comment: Oh yes of course! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^2}=e$$

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it might be of interest to present a way forward that relies only on Bernoulli's Theorem and the squeeze theorem.  To that end we proceed.

---

This is as simple as $1$, $2$, and $3$.

First, we note that

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\le \frac1{\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)}\tag 1$$

---

Second, applying [**Bernoulli's inequality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) ($(1+x)^n\ge 1+x$ for $x>-1$) to both sides of $(1)$ reveals

$$1+\frac1n\le \left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n\le \frac{1}{1-\frac1n}\tag2$$

---

Third, and finally, applying the squeeze theorem to $(1)$ yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n=1$$

---

And we are done!

Answer (score 0):

You have obtains $$ \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^m =e.$$

In your case, you have that $m=n^2$, then
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2} \right)^{n^2\cdot\frac{1}{n} }=\left[ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2} \right)^{n^2 } \right]^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}}=e^0=1.$$